# Regex to find the name of functions that called another specific function

Tags: c#, regex

Suppose you have a C# class with multiple methods. Some of these methods invoke a function `DoWorkAsync`. I need a regular expression that finds the names of the functions and only the functions that invoke DoWorkAsync. As good luck may have it, all functions have the same signature: `public object %name%(List<object> params)` and all end with a `return null;` safeguard.

For example:

```
...
public object AddData(List<object> params) {
    DoSomething();
    DoSomething();
    DoSomething();
    return null;
}

public object ProcessData(List<object> params) {
    DoSomething();
    DoWorkAsync(); //this is an invocation
    DoSomething();
    return null;
}

public object RemoveData(List<object> params) {
    DoSomething();
    DoSomething();
    DoSomething();
    return null;
}
...
```

I first tried this simple regex (I'm using SingleLine Option so "." matches new lines):

`@"public object (?'funcname'.+?)\(List<object> params\).+?DoWorkAsync\(\);"`

The problem with this is the first function will always match and `funcname` will be `AddData` instead of `ProcessData` as it will eventually find the call to `DoWorkAsync` after opening the function. It doesn't know that the function ended and a new one started. OK, so I read about balancing regex which is supposed to deal with this kind of stuff. I then tried something like:

`@"(?:public object (?'funcname'.+?)\(List<object> params\)(?'count')|.+?DoWorkAsync\(\);.+?|return null;(?'-count'))*(?(count)(?!))"`

This didn't work since, again, it will match two opening functions and two closing "return null". I need it to fail if it finds the return without first finding the function call. I tried other permutations such as:

`@"public object (?'funcname'.+?)\(List<object> params\).+?(?:public object .+?\(List<object> params\)(?!)|DoWorkAsync\(\);.+?).+?return null;"`

But nothing worked. I think that balancing regex might be the answer if I'm able to filter the deepest level only. Alternatively, if balancing doesn't work, then some kind of lookahead such that after finding the opening function, if you lookahead and find another opening function before the function call, it fails.

Anyone has any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it another occurency of [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? May I ask what you trying to achieve? Maybe you want `Find usages` of `DoWorkAsync`?

Comment: To parse a language file i would tend to use a language lexer/parser and not a regex even if you think the structure of that specific file is rather easy.

Comment: @Auditive as you may have noticed, the function invocations I want to find are Async. I need ot ifnd usages of this to replace the calling functions to also be a Async. I know I can use my IDE to find usages., but this code is generated code that I need to process and transform automatically in a pipeline.

Comment: @Ralf is there a library I can use from C#? This is something I need to automate for a pipeline

Comment: You can't effectively "parse" C# code using Regex. You may use simple `Ctrl+F` in, for example, Notepad++ over whole folder with source files and check manually each founded line. If you seeking for a "parsers" - it's not suitable to ask at SO such things, but also already [was answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81406/which-parsers-are-available-for-parsing-c-sharp-code).

Comment: @Auditive That's what I was afraid of. Thanks anyway

Comment: You can inspect the IL to find when a method is called : https://stackoverflow.com/q/24680054/1462295

Comment: @Auditive I was able to solve it using a mix of Balancing groups and nested  searches. see my answer if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I had to do nested regex though. Here is what I did:

1. Find all functions with this regex: `@"public object (?'name'\S+)\(List<object> params\){(?'function'(?:[^{}]*|{(?'depth')|}(?'-depth'))*(?(depth)(?!)))}"`
2. Initialize a queue with the target function I want to replace: `var queue = new Queue<string>(); queue.Enqueue("DoWorkAsync");`
3. Use a while loop to go through the queue:

```
while (queue.Count > 0) {
  var toConvert = queue.Dequeue();
  ...
}
```

4. Inside the while, do a for loop to add any functions that call the function to the queue:

```
foreach (var caller in functions.Where(m => m.Groups["function"].Value.Contains(toConvert)).Select(m => m.Groups["name"].Value)) {
  queue.Enqueue(caller);
}
```

5. After the foreach loop but still inside the while loop, I just do replacements for the calls and definitions:

```
newSource = Regex.Replace(oldSource, $@"{toConvert}\((?'params'(?:[^\(\)]*|\((?'depth')|\)(?'-depth'))*(?(depth)(?!)))\)", $"await {toConvert}(${{params}})");
newSource = Regex.Replace(newSource, $@"public object {toConvert}\(List<object> params\)", $"public async Task<object> {toConvert}(List<object> params)");
```

And that is it!

One caveat I found was that if any of the functions is recursive, it will add itself to the queue and loop infinitely. this can be fixed by having a Set of already converted functions and filtering them out in the foreach.